# Exporting Chart object as jpg wont work with screenupdating turned off

Tags: excel, vba, export, jpeg

Ok, ive looked at many different forums to try to find out why my code isnt working with screenupdating set to false. Im trying to export a range as a jpg image using a chart overlay, nothing really complicated there. But when i turn screenupdating off it just exports a blank image (all white) at the correct dimensions and the correct name but no image, why would screenupdating have anything to do with what is copied to the clipboard, thanks for any help in advance.

Attempt #1 (Doesn't work):

```
Private Sub CreateList()

On Error Resume Next
Range("Title") = "Priority List Last Updated: " & Now()
Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:K10")
rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
    .Name = "Chart1"
    .Activate
End With

ActiveChart.Paste
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart.Export ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Priority Top 16.jpg"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Delete

End Sub
```

Attempt #2 (Doesn't work):

```
Private Sub CreateList()

On Error Resume Next
Range("Title") = "Priority List Last Updated: " & Now()
Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = Range("A1:K10")
rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

With ActiveSheet
    .ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
    .Name = "Chart1"
    .Activate
    With ActiveChart
        .Paste
        .Export ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Priority Top 16.jpg"
        .Delete
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Attempt #3 (Works with screenupdating = True):

```
Private Sub CreateList()

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

On Error Resume Next
Range("Title") = "Priority List Last Updated: " & Now()
Dim rgExp As Range: Set rgExp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:K10")
rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap

With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
    .Name = "Chart1"
    .Activate
End With

ActiveChart.Paste
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart.Export ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Priority Top 16.jpg"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Delete
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me:

```
Private Sub CreateList()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim rgExp As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set sht = Sheet1

    Set rgExp = sht.Range("A1:K10")
    rgExp.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture


    With sht.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=10, Top:=10, _
                        Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
        With .Chart
            .Paste
            .Export ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Priority Top 16.jpg"
        End With
        .Delete

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I did use a different `Format` parameter for the copy - don't know if that's the key.